# Co-Author from Industry collabrator

Tags: authorship

I have one question: if i did some contribution to experiment setup design /software /process model development but it I did substantial contribution to other criteria  (Drafting -Logistics- Industry support financiallyand technically , reviewing and modifying paper....)  which raise the paper to be accepted by the journal and also follow up and provide advice as from industry to direct the research , do i still not be qualified as a co-author at least the last one? then what my credit in this work, just an acknowledgment ?

Comment: Perhaps the ICMJE's guidelines on authorship can be of use? http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html

Answer (score 1):

You have made a scientific contribution, which (generally) merits co-authorship (unless it was a particularly small contribution).